# Highlight all characters that are not in regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to write function in JavaScript - AngularJS which gets a string and highlights all characters that are not in `[ A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)\+#!@$%,."<>^=\\]`.

How do I find characters that are *not* from this regular expression? (Pay attention that the string comes from users so convert it to HTML may be not good.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split(/([ A-Za-z0-9_\-\(\)\+#!@$%,."<>^=\\]+)/)` it should return an array with every second entry being the correct parts, and the odd parts being the incorrect parts.

See
http://blog.getify.com/to-capture-or-not/#Stumble